# Generating Go method set with reflection

Tags: go

Is it possible to generate an interface or method set of a struct at runtime with reflection?

For example:

```
type S struct {
    a int
}

func (s *S) Fn(b int) int {
    return s.a + b
}

type I interface {
    Fn(a int) int
}

func main() {
    var x I = &S{a: 5}
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", x.Fn)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", reflect.TypeOf(x).Method(0))

    var y I
    y.Fn = x.Fn // This fails, but I want to set y.Fn at runtime.
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", reflect.TypeOf(y).Method(0))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/agH2fQ4tZ_

To clarify, I'm trying to build a middleware library so interface I contains the http handlers and I want to wrap each hander with some sort of req/response logging so I need to return a new interface I where each function in new Interface I wraps the original + some logging.

Comment: Describe the handler interface used in this scenario. Is it http.Handler or something else?

Comment: It isn't http handler so there isnt a nice generic interface for the handler. Basically I want the middleware library to support a generic interface I or J, where I has a set of methods and J has another set of methods.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to handle this for interfaces I and J.

```
type I interface { Fn1(a int) int }
type J interface { Fn2(a int) int }

type Y struct {       // Y implements I by calling fn
   fn func(a int) int
}

func (y Y) Fn1(a int) int { return y.fn(a) }

type Z struct {       // Z implements J by calling fn
   fn func(a int) int
}

func (z Z) Fn2(a int) int { return y.fn(a) }

var y I = Y{fn: x.Fn}
var z J = Z{fn: x.Fn}
```

There's no need to use reflection.

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/OzGrBHj-p5)

Comment: I'm trying to do it a little more generically because it's meant to be a middleware library. Is it possible if I don't hard code Y implementing Fn?

Comment: Y is coded to call an arbitrary function in its implementation of I.  Replace I with http.Handler or whatever interface your framework uses.